# Angular IO Protractor tests with mocked back-end

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, protractor

I wish to perform some tests in my [Angular IO](https://v4.angular.io/) app using [Protractor](https://www.protractortest.org/#/), however, I was unable to find any solution that allows me to mock back-end services. The only solutions I've found were all to Angular JS. Can anyone point me in the right direction, be it 3rd party libraries with the above mentioned functionality or some native stuff I could use?
Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Hello, I was finally able to mock back-end services as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56023438/mock-services-using-server-js-and-proxy-config-json-using-protractor